# Create a json map using bash

Tags: python, json, bash, dictionary, github-actions

I have the following GitHub actions step.

The workflow takes as input a comma separated list of python (`major.minor`) versions,  infers the full (`major.minor.patch`) version and sets then as outputs to be leveraged by a subsequent job.

Here it goes:

```
      - name: get full python versions
        id: set-python-matrix
        env:
          pversions: ${{ inputs.python_versions }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
          OUT=""
          for version in ${pversions//,/ }
          do
              docker pull python:${version}-buster
              VER=$(docker inspect python:${version}-buster | jq '.[0].Config.Env' | grep PYTHON_VERSION | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d'"' -f 1)
              OUT+="${VER},"
          done
          PYTHON_BUILDS=$(echo "\"${OUT::-1}\"" | jq -c 'split(",")')
          echo "python_builds=${PYTHON_BUILDS}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

This works as expected. So I follow up by calling a job that uses those versions in a `matrix` strategy

```
 build-python-images:
    name: build the python images
    needs:
      - create-python-and-debian-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-builds: ${{ fromJSON(needs.create-python-and-debian-matrix.outputs.python_builds) }}
      fail-fast: true
    uses: MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/reusable.yaml@master
    with:
      image_name: python-custom
      image_tag: ${{ matrix.python-builds }}}
```

Here is the challenge:

I **also** need a correspondence between the `major.minor` and `major.minor.patch` since at the end of the day I want to name my image with `major.minor` (and not `major.minor.patch`) although the later is **also** needed. So I want to be able to do sth like this

```
 build-python-images:
    name: build the python images
    needs:
      - create-python-and-debian-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-builds: ${{ fromJSON(needs.create-python-and-debian-matrix.outputs.python_builds) }}
      fail-fast: true
    uses: MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/reusable.yaml@master
    with:
      image_name: python-custom/${{ matrix.python-versions.python-builds-not-full }}} # <- here I wanna use `major.minor`
      image_tag: ${{ matrix.python-versions.python-builds }}} # <-- here I use the `major.minor.patch`)
```

I assume the way to go about it is having my step above producing the output yielding something like a `json` map e.g. so that I use values such as `${{ matrix.python-versions.majorminorpatch }}` and `${{ matrix.python-versions.majorminor }}`

I literaly have no clue how to do thus with `bash` so any help / hints will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to generate 2 outputs / variables? One with the `major.minor` version map, and one with the `major.minir.patch` version map?

Comment: I can see your point, but how will I be able during the `matrix` strategy execution make sure that `${{ matrix.python-versions.full }}` corresponds to `3.9.17` and `${{ matrix.python-versions.short }}` correspond to `3.9`?

Comment: Yes, you could have 2 matrix variables (`python-builds-full` and `python-builds-short`) based from the previous job outputs.

Comment: could you provide a working-like example because I don't see how this can be done?

Comment: I made an example [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester70.yml) with the 2 outputs concepts I suggested (I don't have the expression to remove the path from the major.minor.patch expression, but I informed where it could be done).

Comment: The problem with this example is that ALL full versions will run against ALL `major.minor` versions

Comment: Ok. If you want to only run the full version with the associated major.minor version, in that case I would go deeper and add a step inside the reusable workflow to separate both variables based on the matrix full version informed.